# iCal and Google Calendar Syncing

Tags: data-synchronization, ical, google-calendar

Is there a way to sync my iCalendar to my Google Calendar? I use the iCal application as my primary calendar resource, and I need to share that data via GoogleCalendar with my colleagues and I cannot figure out how to do this. I am able to get the data from my GoogleCalendar to show up on my iCal, but I cannot do the reverse (I want data created on the iCal to upload/sync directly to the GoogleCalendar).. I have OSX Lion and iCal 6.0

Answer (score 4):

To do so just:

1. On **iCal** go to **Preferences / Accounts**.
2. In the panel on the left, click the **+** button to add an account.
3. Fill in the information, being:

**Account Type:** Google. Although you can either use *Automatic* or *CalDAV*, and the System will *detect* the proper account type.

**Email Address:** The email which you are using to log into the Calendar. The *@domain.com* part should be written too.

**Password:** Well, the password for that account. If you are using *2-Step verification* you must use an [application-specific password](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=es&answer=185833).

Doing this, by **default**, will sync any calendars that appear in **My Calendars** on the web, as well as the **Contact's birthdays and events**.

Adding additional calendars, or removing any of them from syncing, you must go to the [Account Sync Configuration Page](https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect?pli=1), and select the calendars you'd like to be displayed. After doing so, refreshing iCal will display the new configuration.

Comment: I was able to do this alreadym but that is not my goal- completing this step does not make the content already on my iCal sync to my googlecalendar- that is my goal. Any ideas?

Comment: The "Contact's birthdays" is not shown in Google Calendar (neither in Account Sync Configuration Page). That is exactly the one I'm missing in google. Any idea how to solve?